# xaf using existing module in a new application

Tags: devexpress, xaf

I need to use a module in my new xaf windows application. The module has web references and when I drag it in module class the web references are automatically added. I deleted the references but when I use its business object nothing is visible and everything is disabled. I suspect that this is to due to web references but unfortunately I can't interfere this module's code directly. Could showing a module with web references be made possible in a windows application? Any advices?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather vague. Are you saying it works fine from a web-based XAF application?

This sounds like a web reference question rather than anything to do specifically with DevExpress XAF. There are many resources available such as this from MSDN: [Walkthrough: Connecting to Data in a Web Service (Windows Forms)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171891.aspx).

If your webservice is responsible for pulling in the data, it may be a little complicated for XAF. The best approach would be to contact the [DevExpress support center](https://www.devexpress.com/support/center) with a small example.